# How to tell where these RTF files were created

Tags: rtf

I have this bizarre situation. I have a number of RTF files (about 50 of them) and I am trying some skinning software with an installer.

I found that one of the files will render correctly for the colours:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang2057\deflangfe2057{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Arial;}{\f1\froman\fprq2\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}}
{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.18362}\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\nowidctlpar\f0\fs20 The author of this program cannot be held responsible for any data lost during the use of, or as a result of using, this program. You use this program entirely at your own risk.\f1\par
}
```

But all the others will not. Here is an example:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1040\deflangfe1040{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Arial;}}
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;}
{\*\generator Msftedit 5.41.15.1507;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\cf1\f0\fs24 L'autore di questo programma non pu\'f2 essere giudicato responsabile della perdita di alcun dato durante l'uso, o come conseguenza dell\rquote uso del programma. Usate questo programma solamente a vostro rischio. L\rquote aiuto in linea \'e8 presente negli strumenti del programma. \caps\'e8\caps0  disponibile anche il file della guida completa. Sentitevi liberi di inviarmi i vostri suggerimenti per migliorare il programma.\par
}
```

I am not a RTF guru but i noticed this difference at least between the two files:

- generator Riched20 10.0.18362
- generator Msftedit 5.41.15.1507

The RTF files were provided to me by many translators over the years. I just did a test file with WordPad and these are the results:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.18362}\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\f0\fs22\lang9 test\par
}
```

Does this mean that the other RTF documents were created with Microsoft Word?